# reading from serial port pyserial rs485

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, rs485

I found pySerial rs485 example -> https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/rs485.py

Does anyone know how read function should look (any loop or specific sets RTS)? How I should implement communication (write my own data to device 1)->(read data from device 1)->(send data to device 2)

Thank You

Comment: Why using RTS pin (Using RTS pins causes low performance)? another  question `why don't use Device addressing?` If you need an additional pine, the IC 74hc14 and a 100nf capacitor provide you with automatic direction determination(max 115.2kbps).

Comment: Im using RTS because I have RS 485 (half-duplex) connection. I asked only how to implement a reading with using rs485 in PySerial